# setTimeout/setInterval when file selection dialog is open in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

It appears that Internet Explorer (11) prevents setTimeout/setInterval callbacks from firing while a file input's "select file" dialog window is open. Is there any reliable way of triggering a recurring event (e.g. a heartbeat) while the dialog is open?

Comment: WebWorkers? The file dialog blocks your JS from running, and the only way to break from that is a WebWork (that I can think of)

Comment: Curiously, all JS execution is not blocked. Other handlers (e.g. XHR, websockets) continue to be called.

Comment: Each frame/window has its own thread. I would try your heartbeat from a hidden iframe

Comment: @JuanMendes iframe timeouts/intervals are blocked as well.

Comment: Here's the IE bug tracker ticket: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/952951/settimeout-setinterval-timers-are-paused-while-file-selection-dialog-is-open

Answer (score 3):

Outside of potentially using webworkers, no.

JavaScript is single threaded and native popup windows, such as `alert`, `confirm`, and the file dialog window *block* all JavaScript execution on the main thread until they are close.

Comment: Note that this is specific to IE (for file dialogs at least), or potentially other, specific browsers. It looks like Chrome allows you to interact with the webpage even when the file dialog is still open, so I'd assume a timeout/interval can execute too

Comment: Correct. Chrome, Safari, Firefox all run timeout/interval handlers while file dialogs are open.

Comment: @Ian Ah, thanks for the heads up there.  I only tested it under IE, once a long time back.  Never bothered to check the others.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher No problem. I never would've known except I accidentally encountered it in Chrome when using Gmail to attach a file to an email - I realized I could still interact with the UI and was quite surprised because I assumed the file dialog acted like an alert (in all browsers)

Answer (score 0):

A relatively expensive, but reliable method is to abuse requestAnimationFrame, which does appear to fire while "select file" dialogs are open.

```
var setRequestAnimationFrameTimeout = function(callback, length) {
  var reqId;
  var startTime = new Date();

  var step = function() {
    if ((new Date() - startTime) >= length) {
      callback();
    } else {
      reqId = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
  };

  step();

  return {
    cancel: function() {
      if (reqId !== undefined) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(reqId);
      }
    }

  }
};

var setRequestAnimationFrameInterval = function(callback, length) {
  var reqId;
  var startTime = new Date();
  var nextCall = 0;

  var step = function() {
    var diff = new Date() - startTime;

    if (Math.floor(diff / length) === nextCall) {
      nextCall += 1;
      callback();
    }

    reqId = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  };

  step();

  return {
    cancel: function() {
      if (reqId !== undefined) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(reqId);
      }
    }
  }

};

setRequestAnimationFrameTimeout(function() { console.log('timer'); }, 1000);

var i = 0;
setRequestAnimationFrameInterval(function() { console.log('interval', i++); }, 1000);
```

Note that [only IE 10 and 11 support requestAnimationFrame](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that requestAnimationFrame only fires while the tab is active. Combine this implementation with standard timeouts for more reliability.